# Redshift/F.lux not working on Ubuntu 16.04 with Intel HD Graphics

Tags: graphics, redshift, f.lux

I'm aware of the question asked and answered about Redshift/F.lux but it doesn't seem to work for me, as I have Intel HD Graphics. I can open F.lux and preview but for some reason it has no effect on the screen. I tried it with Redshift and the same thing happens, it has no effect on the display. Why aren't they working for Intel HD Graphics?
I have Intel HD Graphics 520 by the way.

Edit: It seems to be a Unity issue? I'm using Kubuntu now (which uses KDE Plasma) and the problem seems to be fixed. It will still be nice to know why Redshift/F.lux isn't working on Unity.

Answer (score 3):

This is more a comment/further question than an answer:

I have the same trouble. However I use a script to do screen rotation, and so I discovered redshift works when I rotate the screen.

More precisely the behavior is as follows:

1) I run

redshift -v

and it tells me the color temp is 5500K, but there is no visible changes.

2) I then flip my screen and the color temp actually changes. I flip it back
and the change remains.

Similarly when when the color temp changes back to normal I can see the change only after flipping the screen.

Thus a very crude work around is to execute:

xrandr -o left;   xrandr -o normal

just after you run redshift. This flips the screen left and then back to normal and works on my set-up.

Of course it would be much better if someone actually figured out the exact problem in redshift etc..

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo apt-get purge xserver-xorg-video-intel
```

This fixed the problem for me.