# Mouse & keyboard (external and built-in) not working 16.04 - monitor driver-related?

Tags: drivers, keyboard, mouse, touchpad

I was trying to get f.lux working ([Redshift/F.lux not working on Ubuntu 16.04 with Intel HD Graphics](https://askubuntu.com/questions/794158/redshift-f-lux-not-working-on-ubuntu-16-04-with-intel-hd-graphics/818453)), and tried running:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install --reinstall xserver-xorg-video-intel xserver-xorg-core
sudo dpkg-reconfigure xserver-xorg
```

from here ([16.04 - How To Purge Intel Default Drivers & Reinstall Intel Graphic Drivers](https://askubuntu.com/questions/763672/16-04-how-to-purge-intel-default-drivers-reinstall-intel-graphic-drivers)). After rebooting, my inbuilt keyboard and touchpad aren't working any more; neither are my external wireless mounse & keyboard. I think the mouse works for a second or two while the programs in startup programs are opening, but afterwards there's no response. My external wireless mouse and keyboard don't work either. The keyboard works in grub.

I'n new to linux, and fairly out of my depth, so would really appreciate your help, especially if it means I don't have to reinstall ubuntu!

Comment: It may be worth trying a few things..... 
If you're still on 16.04, when the boot options [purple screen] appears there are some options, one of which is "safe mode".
Assuming your keyboard[s] work at this point, try booting into safe mode and see what happens: does it work or not ?
If you're on 17.10 try booting into x.org [at the log in screen] and see what happens.
Also, can you actually log in, with your password ? If yes, then at least you know something is working.
Not much help so far I know, but it is a starting point.

Comment: Thanks. I can get into GRUB and recovery mode. I should have mentioned this, but I tried all of the kernel versions in the list, and the behaviour is the same in all of them.

Comment: Also, if I boot into an upstart version of a kernel, i can login and run commands with the keyboard, so it's not a hardware problem.

Comment: Update: the touchpad and keyboard work fine running ubuntu off the bootable USB drive. And ironically, f.lux works now, which is nice, but rather redundant without touchpad or keyboard...

Comment: I suppose then the simple question would be, is it worth doing a re-install from the USB stick, which will re-set whatever it is that is wrong. 
It may not be the best solution, but once you've done your back up it may be the quickest way to solve it.
A hammer to crack a nut.... ?